# Swift Combine, how to cancel the execution

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, combine

I'm new to Combine and I'm trying to understand it by solving the "old" problems

My goal is to make the process cancelable, but even I called the `.cancel()` method right after (or with sort delay) the `printFizzbuzz()` method, the code still keeping running(around 3 secs) until finishing

I've tried the code below in the new Xcode project, still the same

```
import Foundation
import Combine

enum PrinterError: Error {
    case indexError(String)
    case subscriptionError(String)
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .indexError(let descpription):
            return descpription
        case .subscriptionError(let description):
            return description
        }
    }
}

struct FizzbuzzPrinter {
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    mutating func printFizzbuzz(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int, handler: @escaping (_ result: Result<Int,PrinterError>) -> Void) {
        guard toIndex > fromIndex else {
            handler(.failure(.indexError("toIndex must larger than fromIndex")))
            return
        }

        var currentIndex: Int = fromIndex
        
        Array<Int>(fromIndex ..< toIndex).publisher
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { index in
                currentIndex = index
            }, receiveCancel: {
                handler(.failure(.subscriptionError("cancaled at \(currentIndex)")))
            })
            .map { number -> String in
                switch (number.isMultiple(of: 3), number.isMultiple(of: 5) ) {
                case (true, true):
                    return "fizzbuzz at \(number)"
                case (true, false):
                    return "fizz at \(number)"
                case (false, true):
                    return "buzz at \(number)"
                case (false, false):
                    return String()
                }
            }
            .filter{ !$0.isEmpty }
            .sink { _ in
                handler(.success(currentIndex))
            } receiveValue: { print($0)}
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
        
    }
    
    mutating func cancelAll() {
        subscriptions.forEach{ $0.cancel()}
    }
}

var fizzBuzzPrinter = FizzbuzzPrinter()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    fizzBuzzPrinter.printFizzbuzz(fromIndex: 1, toIndex: 60001) { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let printerError):
            print(printerError.description)
        case .success(let finishedIndex):
            print("finished at \(finishedIndex)")
        }
    }
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    fizzBuzzPrinter.cancelAll()
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    fizzBuzzPrinter.cancelAll()
}
```

the code prints (last 10 lines):

```
fizz at 59982
fizzbuzz at 59985
fizz at 59988
buzz at 59990
fizz at 59991
fizz at 59994
buzz at 59995
fizz at 59997
fizzbuzz at 60000
finished at 60000
```

I also tried to use the .switchToLatest() operator, still unable to cancel it

```
struct FizzbuzzPrinter {
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    private let publishers = PassthroughSubject<AnyPublisher<Int, Never>, Never>()
    private let finishPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Int,Never>()


    mutating func printFizzbuzz(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int, handler: @escaping (_ result: Result<Int,PrinterError>) -> Void) {
        guard toIndex > fromIndex else {
            handler(.failure(.indexError("toIndex must larger than fromIndex")))
            return
        }

        var currentIndex: Int = fromIndex
        
        publishers
            .switchToLatest()
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { index in
                currentIndex = index
            }, receiveCancel: {
                handler(.failure(.subscriptionError("cancaled at \(currentIndex)")))
            })
            .map { number -> String in
                switch (number.isMultiple(of: 3), number.isMultiple(of: 5) ) {
                case (true, true):
                    return "fizzbuzz at \(number)"
                case (true, false):
                    return "fizz at \(number)"
                case (false, true):
                    return "buzz at \(number)"
                case (false, false):
                    return String()
                }
            }
            .filter{ !$0.isEmpty }
            .sink { _ in
                handler(.success(currentIndex))
            } receiveValue: { print($0)}
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
        
        publishers.send(Array<Int>(fromIndex ..< toIndex)
                            .publisher
                            .eraseToAnyPublisher())
        
    }
    
    mutating func cancel() {
        publishers.send(finishPublisher.eraseToAnyPublisher())
        finishPublisher.send(completion: .finished)
    }
}

var fizzBuzzPrinter = FizzbuzzPrinter()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    fizzBuzzPrinter.cancel()
}
fizzBuzzPrinter.printFizzbuzz(fromIndex: 1, toIndex: 60001) { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let printerError):
        print(printerError.description)
    case .success(let finishedIndex):
        print("finished at \(finishedIndex)")
    }
}
```

I feel that I made a mistake somewhere but I couldn't figure it.

++++++++++++++++++Update: +++++++++++++++++++

Thanks @matt
I changed the publisher to a Timer based one and it works now

```
        Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common)
            .autoconnect()
            .scan(fromIndex) { current, _ in
                current + 1
            }
            .prefix(toIndex - fromIndex)
```

++++++++++++++++++Update: 2 +++++++++++++++++++

based on @matt comment

```
.subscribe(on: DispatchQueue(label: "serial queue"))
```

and @matt Link: [link](https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html#SECexertingbackpressure) the last section "Exerting Backpressure"

```
            .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)){ num in
                Just(num).delay(for: .seconds(0.01), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            }
```

both works

Thanks!!

++++++++++++++++++Update: 3 +++++++++++++++++++

I modified my previous codes to become a more generic one and found out using

```
.subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
```

and

```
.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
```

works best for me, the speed will not limited by hard coded timeInterval limit, not blocking each other and individually cancelable

I called the below code (some unrelated logics not included)

```
typealias CancelableIntTaskType = CancelableTask<AnyPublisher<Int, Never>>
var cancelableIntTasks = CancelableIntTaskType()
var taskIdArray = [UUID?]()

taskIdArray = [
    startFizzBuzzTask(50, -80, &cancelableIntTasks),
    startFizzBuzzTask(100, 200, &cancelableIntTasks),
    startFizzBuzzTask(600, 1000, &cancelableIntTasks),
    startFizzBuzzTask(2000, 2600, &cancelableIntTasks)
]

checkAllTasksStarted(taskIdArray)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0001) {
    if let id = taskIdArray.compactMap({$0}).first {
        cancelableIntTasks.cancelTaskWithID(id)
    }
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0002) {
    cancelableIntTasks.cancelAll()
}
```

outputs

```
*id 52F started
id:52F val: 100 progress 0.0%
id:52F val: 101 progress 1.0%
id:52F val: 102 progress 2.0%
id:52F val: 103 progress 3.0%
id:52F val: 104 progress 4.0%
id:52F val: 105 progress 5.0%
id:52F val: 106 progress 6.0%
id:52F val: 107 progress 8.0%
id:52F val: 108 progress 8.0%
id:52F val: 109 progress 9.0%
id:52F val: 110 progress 10.0%
id:52F val: 111 progress 11.0%
id:52F val: 112 progress 12.0%
*id 9EA started
id:52F val: 113 progress 13.0%
id:52F val: 114 progress 15.0%
id:52F val: 115 progress 15.0%
*id 97B started
id:52F val: 116 progress 16.0%
id:52F val: 117 progress 17.0%
id:52F val: 118 progress 18.0%
id:9EA val: 600 progress 0.0%
id:9EA val: 601 progress 1.0%
id:97B val: 2000 progress 0.0%
id:9EA val: 602 progress 1.0%
id:9EA val: 603 progress 1.0%
id:9EA val: 604 progress 1.0%
id:97B val: 2001 progress 1.0%
id:9EA val: 605 progress 2.0%
id:97B val: 2002 progress 1.0%
id:52F val: 119 progress 19.0%
id:9EA val: 606 progress 2.0%
4 tasks initiated 3 started
task at index 0 failed
id:97B val: 2003 progress 1.0%
id:52F val: 120 progress 20.0%
id:9EA val: 607 progress 2.0%
id:97B val: 2004 progress 1.0%
id:9EA val: 608 progress 2.0%
id:52F val: 121 progress 21.0%
id:97B val: 2005 progress 1.0%
id:9EA val: 609 progress 3.0%
id:97B val: 2006 progress 1.0%
id:9EA val: 610 progress 3.0%
id:97B val: 2007 progress 2.0%
id:9EA val: 611 progress 3.0%
id:97B val: 2008 progress 2.0%
id:9EA val: 612 progress 3.0%
id:97B val: 2009 progress 2.0%
id:9EA val: 613 progress 4.0%
id:97B val: 2010 progress 2.0%
id:9EA val: 614 progress 4.0%
id:97B val: 2011 progress 2.0%
id:52F val: 122 progress 22.0%
id:9EA val: 615 progress 4.0%
id:52F val: 123 progress 23.0%
id:9EA val: 616 progress 4.0%
id:52F val: 124 progress 24.0%
id:9EA val: 617 progress 5.0%
id:52F val: 125 progress 25.0%
id:97B val: 2012 progress 2.0%
id:9EA val: 618 progress 5.0%
**52F canceled at 125 progress: 25.0%
**97B canceled at 2012 progress: 2.0%
**9EA canceled at 619 progress: 5.0%
id:9EA val: 619 progress 5.0%
id:52F val: 126 progress 26.0%
```

+++++++++++++++++++update 4+++++++++++++++++++

Just made a project for learning ways to cancel / resume the tasks

https://github.com/hgtlzyc/PokemonDisplay

Comment: Hi @matt I am trying to make the time consuming process in printFizzbuzz() 
 cancelable at anytime (also replaceable with new task) and print out (at what index) the process got canceled// I read that " Canceling a subscription frees up any resources previously allocated by attaching the Subscriber.", so I first tried to cancel the subscriptions in FizzbuzzPrinter to cancel the "fizzbuzz" process but it did not work/ then I tried to use the .switchToLatest() operator to terminate the process early but still not working

Comment: The trouble is, it's not just time consuming, it's blocking.

Comment: @matt I think you are right, I tried ".subscribe(on: DispatchQueue(label: "serial queue")) " it becomes cancelable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your publisher is too artificially crude: it is not asynchronous.  An array publisher just publishes all its values at once, so you are canceling too late; and you are blocking the main thread.  Use something like a timer publisher instead, or use a flatmap with a delay and backpressure.

Comment: I think you are right, I changed it to a timer based one it works now, currently I have a hard time understand the way to use "a flatmap with a delay and backpressure", I will do some more reading, research and update my post later// Thanks

Comment: See https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html#SECexertingbackpressure